# QDialog::accept quits Main Application

Tags: qt, dialog, qdialog

I have a `ClientSocket` Class which is a `TcpSocket` in a certain state of conversation I need to ask the user to enter a Communication password. So I've created a Dialog `DG::ChallangeDialog` . in `DG::ChallangeDialog`s ctor I've

```
ui->setupUi(this);
QPushButton* okButton = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok);
if(okButton != 0x0){
    okButton->setText("Challange");
}
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(acceptedSlot()));
```

`acceptedSlot` again emits a signal `challanged(QString)`

```
void ChallangeDialog::acceptedSlot(){
    QString text = ui->passBox->text();
    emit challanged(text);
}
```

in `ClientSocket` I do

```
    case Hallo:{
            if(m->message().startsWith("welcome")){
                DG::ChallangeDialog* dlg = new DG::ChallangeDialog;
                dlg->setModal(true);
                connect(dlg, SIGNAL(challanged(QString)), this, SLOT(challanged(QString)));
                dlg->exec();
                /*
                DG::MessagePacket* res = new DG::MessagePacket((int)Hallo);
                res->setMessage("challange");
                send(res);
                state = Challange;
                */
            }
        }break;
```

In `ClientSocket::challange` **slot** I send a Message *challange* (text) over the socket and store the password.

---

and I expect the Dialog to hide there and the normal socket conversation to continue. and after the Dialog is accepted or rejected the main application quits (It quits it doesn't crash). Why ?

- My Application has no Other Widgets. I just works like an QCoreApplication. But still I've used QApplication cause I've some GUI Needs.

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious in your code (apart from not checking the result of `.exec()`, and having two slots and a custom signal when you could have simply had a getter in your `ChallangeDialog` given the usage - and it's usually called a challenge). Are you certain it's not crashing? There could be a problem if you're doing anything lasting the `ClientSocket.challanged`. (i.e does it still run without crashing if you run it in a debugger, or maybe valgrind?)

Comment: Its not Crashing Its `exited with code 0` What I think is when the User presses the Ok or Cancel Button It quits the `QApplication`'s event Loop. But why ?

Comment: there is no call to `quit` in the code you posted, the problem is probably somewhere else. Run through your code in the debugger until you see where it bails out.

Comment: The Debugger Says Application exited normally. One thing I'd like to mention I've no other widget or MainWindow in My Application. in main() I construct a `ClientSocket` Connect to a host with it. and in between of the conversation the ClientSocket sometimes opens a Dialog.

Comment: then something's wrong with your code structure somewhere unrelated with the code you posted if it's leaving the event loop when you're not expecting it. Use your debugger to _trace_ your code when it enters that challanged slot, and see where it goes.

Comment: I've Updated My question a bit. Do you guess anything wrong in it ?

Comment: the code you added does not add anything to our knowledge of how your code is structured. If you don't have a trace of where your code is leaving the event loop (from your debugging session), or more information about how your app is structured _precisely_, can't help.

Comment: Well in main() I Instantiate a ClientSocket. and ClientSocket has a msgRecieved Slot. wheneven a new Message appears over the socket this slot is invoked. and in it ClientSocket maintains a State Information. When It is in Hallo State if it gets "welcome" string from serversocket it asks the user to enter a communication password (through the dialog). which it stores in a member variable. and then sends "challange" text over the socket. If I remove the dialog part it works perfectly.

Comment: Has it to do anything with catching the accepted signal to accepted slot of this object ? e.g. Is it Okay to catch the accepted signal in accepted Slot of the same dialog ?

Comment: I've tried using a QMessageBox in that same place and I wondered even after a QMessageBox is accepted or rejected My Application/Event loop Quits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the only window that is shown at this time?  If so, I would guess that your [QApplication](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qapplication.html) instance is set to [quit when the last window is closed](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop).  It is true by default.

If this is the case, you should explicitly set this to false before showing any windows.

Comment: Thanks Thats What I was Searching for.