# PyQt dialog closes entire app on exit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a PyQt wizard that includes a dialog box that asks the user a question.  This dialog box is optional and only for use if the user wants it.  A button sends a signal that the app receives and opens the window.  The problem I have is that when the dialog is closed, it closes the whole app with it.  How do I make sure that when the dialog is closed, the main app stays open and running?  Here the code that handles the dialog box:

```
def new_item(self):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.exec_()
```

I tried adding a 'Cancel' button to close it manually but the result was the same, the whole app closed.

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.cancel, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), Dialog.close)
```

Comment: Why do you create `app`?

Comment: Ah ha, I removed `app` and it worked properly.  I got the code from the file pyuic returned.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create new `QApplication` objects in your code, and I am not surprised that destroying that object closes the application.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.dialog = QtGui.QMessageBox(self)
        self.dialog.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok | QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        self.dialog.setIcon(QtGui.QMessageBox.Question)
        self.dialog.setText("Click on a button to continue.")

        self.pushButtonQuestion = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonQuestion.setText("Open a Dialog!")
        self.pushButtonQuestion.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonQuestion_clicked)

        self.layoutHorizontal = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutHorizontal.addWidget(self.pushButtonQuestion)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonQuestion_clicked(self):
        result = self.dialog.exec_()

        if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok:
            print "Dialog was accepted."

        elif result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel:
            print "Dialog was rejected."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Dialog.reject` instead of `Dialog.close`

`.close()` method is being used mith QMainWindow Widget, `.reject()` with QDialog.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had `QSystemTrayIcon` as an "entry point" to my app instead of `QMainWindow` or `QWidget`.

Calling `.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)` on my main `QApplication` instance helped, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6322631/5232529)